# Filtro em consulta

Tags: java

```
modelo.setNumRows(0);
    Class.forName(Auxiliar.AcessoBanco.getDriver());
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(Auxiliar.AcessoBanco.getUrl(), Auxiliar.AcessoBanco.getUser(), Auxiliar.AcessoBanco.getPass());
    String query1 = "Select id_ct, ORDEM ,CDLINHA, TIPOL,SETOR ,TCPERFIL,BPCS,DPERFIL ,PROJETO ,OEM,N_DESENHO ,N_PLANO,OPERACAO,EQUIPAMENTO, DESCTESTE,COMPLEMENTO, TCTESTE ,"
            + "ESPEC_MIN,ESPEC_MAX, ESPEC_UNID,ESPEC_TEXTO,REFERENCIA,"
            + "FREQUENCIA,FREQ_UNID,PRODUTO,ORIGEM,TIPO,ESPECTEXTO,"
            + "FREQTEXTO,LAB from QRY_RESULT where TCPERFIL = " + txt_perfil.getText() + "ORDER BY ORDEM asc";
```

Como vocês podem ver.. eu faço uma busca por um "Perfil" que contem vários teste cadastrado nele, mas agora estou precisando filtrar os teste que são relacionado a coluna "LAB" e que estejam "Sim" para que a pessoa do lab só coloque os valores nos teste de laboratório. Alguém sabe me dizer como eu acrescento essa busca nessa consulta?

Comment: Tá faltando informações ai. Você tem essa tabela QRY_RESULT e está querendo filtrar os registros que contém o valor "LAB" em uma coluna específica? Tente explicar melhor!

Comment: Seguinte.. eu tenho um DefaultTableModel onde eu trago vário teste relacionado a um "perfil" q é especificado "TCPERFIL = " + txt_perfil.getText() +",  só que agora eu preciso trazer apenas alguns testes relacionado a coluna "LAB" que contem o valor "Sim". e trazer para pessoa cadastrar

Comment: coluna "LAB" é uma coluna no banco de dados?

Comment: isso e nela tem valores "Sim, Não"

Comment: respondi ai. passa o feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para trazer somente os registros com a coluna `LAB` igual a `Sim`.

Modifique sua query para:

```
String query1 = "Select id_ct, ORDEM ,CDLINHA, TIPOL,SETOR ,TCPERFIL,BPCS,DPERFIL ,PROJETO ,OEM,N_DESENHO ,N_PLANO,OPERACAO,EQUIPAMENTO, DESCTESTE,COMPLEMENTO, TCTESTE ,"
            + "ESPEC_MIN,ESPEC_MAX, ESPEC_UNID,ESPEC_TEXTO,REFERENCIA,"
            + "FREQUENCIA,FREQ_UNID,PRODUTO,ORIGEM,TIPO,ESPECTEXTO,"
            + "FREQTEXTO,LAB from QRY_RESULT where TCPERFIL = " + txt_perfil.getText() + " and LAB = 'Sim' ORDER BY ORDEM asc";
```

adicionando `and LAB = 'Sim'`